Problem with text selection with a Kotlin chip
I am not able to make the text change for each selection of a chip, when Java is selected, I try to make Java appear in the textView, and so on with the other chips (Kotlin, C++) but it is not working, I have tried setOnCheckedChangeListener but in android studio it appears crossed out, I don't know if it has anything to do with it
val selecciones = findViewById<ChipGroup>(R.id.selecciones)
        val textoLenguaje = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lenguaje)

        selecciones.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            val lenguajeSeleccionado = when (checkedId) {
                R.id.java -> getString(R.string.java)
                R.id.kotlin -> "Kotlin"
                R.id.cplus -> "C++"
                else -> ""
            }

            textoLenguaje.text = lenguajeSeleccionado
        }

<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/selecciones"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/java"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/java"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            />
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/kotlin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/kotlin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/java"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/cplus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/c"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/kotlin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            />



    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto_estoy_programando"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/estoy_programando_en"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selecciones"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/selecciones"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lenguaje"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text=" Java"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/texto_estoy_programando"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/selecciones"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        />


What is a "tn Kotlin chip"?

My mistake, I wanted to refer to a chip in Kotlin
